# how to render array of object in html element using javascript using map function ? Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

how to render an array of object in HTML element using javascript using map function (without React).

### So, that when insert an object in user detail it should create a card for the user dynamically.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOgjH.jpg)

```js
var Usrdata = document.querySelector('.box');

var userDetail = [
    {name:"sunil",age:"24",place:"delhi",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"sujan",age:"22",place:"assam,",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"abishek",age:"26",place:"kolkata",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"chiranjeev",age:"20",place:"bangalore",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
]

userDetail.map(user=>{
    console.log (
        user.name,
        user.age,
        user.place,
        user.country,
        user.avatar
    )
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="customCard">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="test1" class="col-sm-4 box">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "how to...." isn't an acceptable question here in most instances.  See [ask].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `map` to create DOM and attach to the `test1` element:

```js
var Usrdata = document.querySelector('.box');

var userDetail = [
    {name:"sunil",age:"24",place:"delhi",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"sujan",age:"22",place:"assam,",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"abishek",age:"26",place:"kolkata",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
    {name:"chiranjeev",age:"20",place:"bangalore",avatar:"./image/abc.jpg",country:"India"},
]

document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = userDetail.map(user => 
    `<div>
      <div>Name: ${user.name}</div>
      <div>Age: ${user.age}</div>
      <div>Place: ${user.place}</div>
      <div>Country: ${user.country}</div>
      <div>Avatar: ${user.avatar}</div>
    </div>`
).join('')
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="customCard">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="test1" class="col-sm-4 box">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```