# How do I fix the code in Javascript to avoid repetitive elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, frontend

index.html

```
 <!--FIRST PIZZA---FIRST CHUNK OF HTML CODE-->
        <div class="column-pizza-1">
          <a href="">
            <div class="pizza-item--img">
              <img src="" id="pizza-img-1" />
            </div>
            <div class="pizza-item--add" id="selected-1">Add</div>
          </a>
          <div class="pizza-item--price" id="pizza-price-1">Rs. --</div>
          <div class="pizza-item--name" id="pizza-name-1">--</div>
          <div class="pizza-item--desc" id="pizza-desc-1">--</div>
        </div>
<!--SECOND PIZZA---SECOND CHUNK OF HTML CODE-->
            <div class="column-pizza-2">
              <a href="">
                <div class="pizza-item--img">
                  <img src="" id="pizza-img-2" />
                </div>
                <div class="pizza-item--add" id="selected-2">Add</div>
              </a>
              <div class="pizza-item--price" id="pizza-price-2">Rs. --</div>
              <div class="pizza-item--name" id="pizza-name-2">--</div>
              <div class="pizza-item--desc" id="pizza-desc-2">--</div>
              <div class="pizza-item--sizes" id="pizza-size-2">
            </div>
```

pizzas.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tandoori Paneer",
    "img": "/images/pizza.png",
    "price": 200,
    "sizes": [0, 100, 200],
    "description": "Spiced paneer, Onion, Green Capsicum & Red Paprika in Tandoori Sauce",
    "cheese": [0, 100, 0]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Veggie Supreme",
    "img": "images/pizza.png",
    "price": 250,
    "sizes": [0, 100, 200],
    "description": "Black Olives, Green Capsicum, Mushroom, Onion, Red Paprika, Sweet Corn",
    "cheese": [0, 100, 0]
  }
]
```

index.js

```
//FIRST PIZZA - loading json data and showing it on index.html page
fetch("pizzas.json").then((response) =>
  response.json().then((data) => {
    //console.log(data[0].name);
    document.querySelector("#pizza-img-1").src = data[0].img;
    document.querySelector("#pizza-name-1").innerHTML = data[0].name;
    document.querySelector(
      "#pizza-price-1"
    ).innerHTML = `Rs ${data[0].price.toFixed(2)}`;
    document.querySelector("#pizza-desc-1").innerHTML = data[0].description;
  })
);
//SECOND PIZZA
fetch("pizzas.json").then((response) =>
  response.json().then((data) => {
    //console.log(data[0].name);
    document.querySelector("#pizza-img-2").src = data[1].img;
    document.querySelector("#pizza-name-2").innerHTML = data[1].name;
    document.querySelector(
      "#pizza-price-2"
    ).innerHTML = `Rs ${data[1].price.toFixed(2)}`;
    document.querySelector("#pizza-desc-2").innerHTML = data[1].description;
  })
);
```

**MY DOUBT:** 
As you can see in the above code, I want to display details of two pizza items whose details are stored in json file and I'm using vanilla javascript to load data from json to HTML. And for each each of the pizzas, I have created element in index.html which is not good. Let's suppose in future I want to display details of 50 pizzas, so that would mean creating 50 chunks of code in html.
Can someone please tell me how can I use only one chunk of the HTML code and use it multiple times to create as many pizza items using vanilla javascript.

**MY TAKE ON:**
I was thinking to store the json data as a global variable and then use `onload()` and `ready()` to load data but I'm not sure about how to do it.

Comment: Do the request once, loop thorugh the array that comes as a response, display the information. Look for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967165/how-to-render-array-of-object-in-html-element-using-javascript-using-map-functio This Should help. Also, note that you can easily parse from JSON into plain JS-Objects through the JSON.parse()-API. (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an HTML template in JavaScript and use it over to generate your multiple `<div>` based on data in JSON file.

Using [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can easily use with the [**loops**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/loop)

```js
fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/605b2c5aaee69516ee8a8866/2").then((response) =>
  response.json().then((data) => {

    let jsonSize = data.length;

    let htmlContent = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonSize; i++) {
      let id = data[i].id;
      let name = data[i].name;
      let img = data[i].img;
      let price = data[i].price;
      let sizes = data[i].sizes;
      let description = data[i].description;
      let cheese = data[i].cheese;

      htmlContent += `
           <div class="column-pizza">
            <a href="">
              <div class="pizza-item--img">
                <img src="${img}" id="pizza-img-${i}" />
              </div>
              <div class="pizza-item--add" id="selected-${i}">Add</div>
            </a>
            <div class="pizza-item--price" id="pizza-price-${i}">₹${price}</div>
            <div class="pizza-item--name" id="pizza-name-${i}">${name}</div>
  <div class="pizza-item--desc" id="pizza-desc-${i}">${description}</div>
</div>`;
    }
    document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = htmlContent;

  })
);
```

```css
.column-pizza {
  height: auto;
  width: 50vv;
}


.pizza-item--add,
.pizza-item--price {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.pizza-item--add {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
}

.pizza-item--price {
  background-color: #333;
  /* Gray */
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

PS- Don't have pizza image placeholder, thus using some random  and ️  images.

Comment: Thanks for this. But assume that I need to display 50 pizza items, then I will have to create 50 <div> tags for it, right? Is there any way in which I don't have to create so many <div> tags because I want the application to be feasible.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary In the above code, I am creating 2  ``<div>`` tags using JavaScript, not by hardcoded in HTML.   Thus, if you have 50 or even any number, then also the above code will work without changing a single line of code.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary However, suppose your JSON has 100 items in it. Then it is not a good approach to display the whole 100 items on a single page without any kind of Pagination or Infinite Scrolling approach. For that, we need to use graphQL or a similar kind of thing where we will call on a JSON file instead of an API that fetches data from DB.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary If it helps then do accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo

- you can use async/await to fetch json
- use map to transform the array to tags
- use `innerHTML` to append a bunch of html contents

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async ev => {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
  const data = await res.json()
  const photos = data.slice(0, 100)


  const appEl = document.querySelector('#app')
  appEl.innerHTML = photos.map((photo, index) => {
    return `<div class="photo" style="transition-delay: ${index / 10}s">
                  <div class="image">
                    <a href="${photo.url}"><img src="${photo.thumbnailUrl}" alt="thumbnailUrl" /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="title">
                    <a href="${photo.url}">${photo.title}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>`
  }).join('')
  setTimeout(() => {
    appEl.classList.add('loaded')
  }, 0)
}, false)
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.photo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100vw, -100vh);
}

#app.loaded .photo {
  position: static;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.image {
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.title a {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: midnightblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title a:hover {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```