# Pass values to select tag in html form from file

Tags: html

I have a html form with select tag. Can I pass values to select tag from a text file or excel sheet? On start up the file data should be passed to select tag element. Is there any way to accomplish it using HTML?

PS: I am able to hardcore the values to select tag element but not sure how to pass values from file..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for anything dynamic (like in ur case) you have to use JavaScript or, if you are running SSR, render it in the server and send it to the user then.

Comment: @Lith Can you show some simple example on how to do it using javascript or SSR? I am new to both topics..

Comment: SSR means server side render. basically you render a page on the server and send the result to the user. This way you get the values and put them in a page and only then send it to the user. I do not know what you are using for your server, what programming language and so on hence I can not be at help. You need to google.

Comment: Now for javascript - There are many ways to do it and many tutorials online. I found one simple tutorial with vanilla JavaScript on reading the excel and converting to JSON here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-xls-file-in-javascript-html5 . With that JSON you just need to then map it and render select options. There are also many tutorials for that. here is a simple one i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967165/how-to-render-array-of-object-in-html-element-using-javascript-using-map-functio

Comment: @Lith Thanks for the info.. I will look into it.